# Calling Firebase Remote Config REST API without auth

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-remote-config

I want to use Firebase Remote Config API via REST in a mobile app. Due to technical limitations, I can't use the Android/iOS SDK so I have to resort to the REST API.

However, that API requires authentication using a private key -- obviously I can't include that key in the application.

I don't need any other Firebase service at this time, just the remote config.

How can I work around this limitation? I tried following the guide at https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest, but as mentioned it requires to first generate a short-lived OAuth2 token using the auth API.

Comment: Why can't you add a public key? The purpose of a public key is that it can be known by everybody without harm...

Comment: There's no public key. I have a file from Firebase with a generated private key. You're supposed to authenticate yourself to Firebase using their client library (python, java, etc). Obviously there's also a public key that is sent to Firebase, but using it in an app will still require to put the private key there, too.

Comment: Perhaps you update the question? It currently says " "that API requires authentication using a public key -- obviously I can't include that key in the application". Did you mean "private key"? (Which you really shouldn't put into the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on [using the Remote Config REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest):

> This document describes how you can use the Remote Config REST API to read and modify the set of JSON-formatted parameters and conditions known as the Remote Config template.

So the REST API is for **modifying** Remote Config variables, the type of action you could also do in the Firebase console. It is not for use in regular clients, which **consume** the configuration variables. For that you'll have to use one of the provided clients, as there is no REST API and the wire protocol is not documented.

Comment: It says (as you quote) "*read* and modify", but I get it -- the REST API is not meant to be used by apps.