# Documentation for Firebase Remote Config *Client* API?

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-remote-config, code-documentation

I'm looking for documentation detailing the API that allows clients to connect to [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config). I'm making a Unity project for a platform *other than mobile*, and I've built my own client code for other Firebase products since no client library is available to my knowledge; now, I'm looking to do the same for Remote Config but I can't seem to find any documentation for the actual REST API!

I'm aware of the Remote Config [admin/configuration API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config), but this is NOT what I'm looking for, as it is built for developer/admin accounts to modify remote config data; instead, I'm asking for the API that the official Firebase client libraries use to fetch one single user's configuration.

A link to official or unofficial documentation or easy-to-read sample code would be greatly appreciated! Otherwise, I might end up reverse engineering the Google-provided client libraries and generate some myself.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no publicly documented REST API for accessing Remote Config data from a client. The only supported platforms are the ones for which an SDK is available.

Also see:

- [Firebase Rest api for remote config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43308108/209103)
- [Calling Firebase Remote Config REST API without auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983392/calling-firebase-remote-config-rest-api-without-auth)
- [How to query firebase remote config rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717804/how-to-query-firebase-remote-config-rest-api), where somebody tries to use the (afaik undocumented) REST API in a web app
- 